# App to show exercises solved by students in real time

Tags: secondary-education, interactive-teaching

I'm looking for an app that can be used when the teacher gives a set of exercises to his class to show for each exercise how many students solved it, how many students tried to solve it, etc. The students may use their smartphone to input data in real time. Of course I would also like to be able to check for each student what exercises he has been able to solve. 
Does anyone know an app that can do something like this?

Comment: Perhaps teacher.desmos.com or goformative.com?

Comment: +1 for real shop talk.